# Using electron's Bluetooth module, the output Bluetooth list is garbled

Tags: vue.js, electron

please look at the following code, after scanning out the list of Bluetooth, print out the list, but the driverName is all garbled, and the Bluetooth connection fails.

```js
mainWindow.webContents.on('select-bluetooth-device', (event, deviceList, callback) => {
    console.log('mian-select-bluetooth-device')
    console.log(deviceList)
    
    event.preventDefault()
    selectBluetoothCallback = callback
    const result = deviceList.find((device) => {
      return device.deviceName === 'test'
    })
    if (result) {
      callback(result.deviceId)
    } else {
    }
  })
```

[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSs07.png)